# How can I replace the default kernel with an earlier kernel?

Tags: kernel, petalinux

I am working on petalinux, Linux for xilinx FPGAs. The source code is [here](https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/tree/xlnx_3.8) 
This Linux is having 3.x kernel, and I have been asked to change the kernel to some earlier release version.

What are the general steps for replacing the kernel? I have downloaded an eralier version form kernel.org. What is the next step?

Comment: I recommend against trying. From what I'm reading, the petalinux kernel has some firmware-specific tweaks and patches that aren't in the main kernel yet -- and will almost certainly not patch cleanly into an older kernel. Your best bet is to ask xilinx for an older version of their kernel tree.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But where did you see in the code those firmware-specific tweeks and patches?

Comment: Why *else* do you think they maintain a separate kernel tree?

Answer (score 0):

`make defconfig` or `make menuconfig` the menuconfig option will be time consuming since you will need to set up everything
`make`
`sudo make install`
only use sudo for the install part. Grub (or llvm) should autoupdate on the install but if it does not you might need to do a `sudo grub-mkconfig > grub.cfg` and the `mv grub.cfg /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and check that your kernel is in /boot and if you grep the new grub.cfg for your kernel it shows up. When booting you may need to hold shift (again this is for grub) to be able to pick which kernel you want to boot off of.

Answer (score 0):

The tool chain comes along with its own Linux kernel 3.x in your case and patching this kernel is not a good idea, as this can be shared among multiple projects which use Petalinux.

As asked in your question you have to replace the kernel with older kernel,

> Xilinx maintains its kernel repo where you can find appropriate tags Refer [Linux-xlnx](https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx)

To add any particular kernel into Petalinux project,
Refer [Zynq TRD](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Zynq+Base+TRD+2014.2) Section 5.3 : Add Linux kernel 3.14 support

OR you can make select the

> petalinux-config :: "Linux Component Selection" > "Remote" >

(Fill your Linux-xlnx GIT repo path with tag)

But be cautious last will download the kernel every time when you delete the 'build' directory.

Good Luck !!